# What does admission applied stamp on a passport mean to south africa immigration

Tags: passports, south-africa, denial-of-entry

An immigration officer refused me entry into South Africa and stamped my passport and wrote with a pen (ADMISSION APPLIED). I did not commit any offense, my passport had a little cut on the biometric page, but but all my documents were in place. This was not my first trip to South Africa.

What does ADMISSION APPLIED mean and what are the implications of this stamp in my passport?

Comment: What is your nationality? How frequently do you travel to SA, what’s the purpose of your trips and how long do you stay each time?

Comment: Please upload the stamp

Comment: Welcome Adzartei! Is there a chance the phrase is "ADMISSION DENIED"?

Comment: User has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.